# Only getting fraction of gigabit ethernet speed on home network with windows 10

Tags: home-networking

I have couple PC's running at home for various things but only with a specific one I'm not able to get low speeds on home networking. That specific machine has very old cpu with only 2GB ram, and I think that might be the reason why, I just wanted to confirm my suspicion.

The connection in Windows is indeed showing up as 1000Mbps, and the cables/router is not the culprit, tested.

Is there a way to check if the hardware of that PC is limiting factor (CPU usage doesn't really go up to 100% when transferring files), or somehow optimize the network capability of Windows 10 for such an old machine?

Comment: So many things here, from software to testing method... Let's start with what your testing to and what kind of rates are you getting?

Comment: @acejavelin thanks for trying to help. I'm using FTP file transfers over filezilla, from another w10 machine, usually getting around 50 Mbps, fluctuating (same machine sends to another machine with 500Mbps, same method). By the way the machine I'm getting bad results has an SSD, so that shouldn't be a factor

Comment: "ftp transfers" (plural) is very slow for large volumes of smallish files (think "transaction overhead"). not sure is this is what you are doing

Comment: Your CPU and the amount of memory will have little to no effect on your transfer speeds.

Comment: @Yorik hello, thanks for the help, yeah I'm aware of that and tried with one, large file.

Comment: Note that many common classes of hard disks cannot perform IO at gigabit speed for long periods of time. as slow mechanical disks become less common and older IO bus technologies are phased out, that should correct itself. There are other reasons that transactions with upstream servers may be constrained, like ratelimiting on their firewalls or under-provisioning of bandwidth. I would definitely confirm that you are using Sata3 disks and buses.SSD won't do well when connected to a Sata2 bus.

Comment: How old is "very old"? I recall that 1GHz single-core CPUs could usually handle gigabit Ethernet at line rate, whereas slower CPUs struggled. Windows 10 supposedly requires a 1GHz CPU minimum, so your machine probably isn't so old that it can't do gigabit. Whether 20 additional years of OS bloat is wasting too much CPU is another question…

Comment: @Spiff hey, thanks for the help, yes it's a dual core 2.xGHz something machine, with 2GB ram, so maybe that might be limiting, I think it's a bit below what Win 10 really wants.

Comment: FTP is not a valid test method... I suggest looking into iPerf and testing multiple OS's... Honestly, even your A/V software could be slowing down your speeds. I work as an engineer for an ISP and we often have to test Internet connection speeds up to 2.5Gbps and sometimes higher and in Windows this can become challenging, which is why our high-end test machines all run Linux. That said, you are not looking at speeds like that, however you should be able to achieve ~920Mbps with iPerf assuming two in LAN computers and no limitations from outside influences.

Comment: @acejavelin thank you, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: It turned out to be that the TLS encryption was overpowering the CPU (while using Filezilla as FTP server), so not using it increases the speeds a significant amount, so I guess the bottleneck was the CPU from the beginning.

Comment: please mark your answer as "correct answer" so people know your issue is resolved. Thank you.